# MySQL XDev API - Node.js Connector - client.getSession() never resolve nor throw after few hours

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql-connector, mysql-x-devapi

I use the MySQL XDevAPI connector in nodejs to connect to a MySQL db on the same server. It runs successfully few hours until, at some point `await pool.getSession()` never resolve nor throw any error.

- MySQL is version 8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.3
- NodeJS is 18.0.0
- Mysql XDevConnector for nodejs is v 8.0.29 installed with yarn

I create my client pool with :

```json
{
    pooling : { 
        enabled: true, 
        maxSize: 25, 
        maxIdleTime : 1000, 
        queueTimeout: 2000 
    }
}
```

As I said, for a few hours, the server will work smoothly, and suddently, the connection pool will stop giving me new sessions. The time before it occurs vary from 10/12h to 48h (the website using it receive almost no traffic).

I tried to circumvent this problem by adding a `Promise.race` with a timeout, like this :

```js
await Promise.race([
    pool.getSession(),
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => reject(
            new DBConnectionError(
                'XDEV_GET_SESSION_NEVER_RETURNS',
                'Here we go again...'
            )
        ), 10000)
    })
]);
```

Sometimes, hiting the timeout allow the pool to work for subsequent `pool.getSession` for few minutes until the bug shows up again. Sometimes it takes several calls (3-4) and sometimes, I need to restart my app. It's a very strange and random behavior.

I release every connection after any transaction/request by calling `await con.close()`, and my race timeout is five time greater than the queueTimeout.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By further investigating, I found out that this problem had more to do with a peace of legacy code doing silly things in emulated nested transactions.

Instead of reusing the current connection, it created a new one somewhere and, if a certain condition was fulfilled (the die of a user session for inactivity in this precise case), it would never return the connection to the pool, because the code didn't followed the app design guidelines.

This particular condition caused the bug to occurs at what seemed a "random" frequency, since a user session lifetime can heavily vary among users and app usage.

This is a very project-specific related problem relying on a bug in private code, but I let this there as a reference if someone encounter a similar issue with the mysql connector : investigate carefully to find unreleased connections.

I believed that the `maxIdleTimeout` parameter would avoid this cases by automaticaly returning an idl connection to the pool, but it doesn't seems to work this way.

## ------ EDIT -------

Even with my fixed code, the bug appeared again.

So, I conducted four types of tests :

1. Raw Testing* the `@mysql/xdevapi` module
2. Raw testing* the `mysql2` module
3. Testing the `@mysql/xdevapi` module with my app architecture
4. Testing the `mysql2` module with my app architecture

[*] By raw testing, I mean testing the package without any private code involved. Only the module involved.

## Raw Testing

### Sequential

We try to execute 500 requests, one at a time, and see what happen :

#### `mysql2`

```js
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

const MAX_CON = Number.parseInt(process.argv[2]) || 120;
const NB_REQ = Number.parseInt(process.argv[3]) || 500;

(async() => {

    try{
        const client = new mysql.createPool(
            {
                host : '127.0.0.1',
                port : 3306,
                user : 'test',
                password : 'test',
                database : 'test',
                connectionLimit : MAX_CON
            }
        );

        const before = Date.now();
        for(let i = 0; i < NB_REQ; i++){
            const con = await client.getConnection();
            await con.query('SELECT 1 from user');
            await con.release();
        }

        const time = (Date.now() - before) / 1000; //in seconds
        const opBySecond = NB_REQ / time;
        console.log('The end : ', { opBySecond, time, NB_REQ, MAX_CON });

        await client.end();

        process.exit(0);
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }

})();
```

#### `@mysql/xdevapi`

```js
const mysql = require('@mysql/xdevapi');

const MAX_CON = Number.parseInt(process.argv[2]) || 120;
const NB_REQ = Number.parseInt(process.argv[3]) || 500;

(async() => {

    try{
        const client = await mysql.getClient(
            {
                host : '127.0.0.1',
                port : 33060,
                user : 'test',
                password : 'test',
                schema : 'test'
            },
            {
                pooling : {
                    maxSize : MAX_CON
                }
            }
        );

        const before = Date.now();
        for(let i = 0; i < NB_REQ; i++){
            const con = await client.getSession();
            const prep = await con.sql('SELECT 1 from user');
            await prep.execute();
            await con.close();
        }

        const time = (Date.now() - before) / 1000;
        const opBySecond = NB_REQ / time;
        console.log('The end : ', { opBySecond, time, NB_REQ, MAX_CON });

        await client.close();

        process.exit(0);
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }

})();
```

Boths scripts run `500` requests with a pool of `60` connections with respective commands :

- `node squential-mysql2.js 60 500`
- `node squential-xdevapi.js 60 500`

And the results :

| Driver | Op / sec | time (s) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mysql2 | 11 111.11 | 0.045 |
| xdevapi | 3 703.70 | 0.135 |

`@mysql/xdevapi` is 3 to 4 times slower than `mysql2` with sequential execution.

### Parallel

#### `mysql2`

```js
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

const MAX_CON = Number.parseInt(process.argv[2]) || 60;
const NB_REQ = Number.parseInt(process.argv[3]) || 500;

(async() => {

    try{
        const client = new mysql.createPool(
            {
                host : '127.0.0.1',
                port : 3306,
                user : 'test',
                password : 'test',
                database : 'test',
                connectionLimit : MAX_CON
            }
        );

        const before = Date.now();
        const promises = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < NB_REQ; i++){
            promises.push(new Promise(async resolve => {
                const con = await client.getConnection();
                await con.query('SELECT 1 from user');
                await con.release();
                resolve();
            }))
        }
        await Promise.allSettled(promises);

        const time = (Date.now() - before) / 1000; //in seconds
        const opBySecond = NB_REQ / time;
        console.log('The end : ', { opBySecond, time, NB_REQ, MAX_CON });

        await client.end();

        process.exit(0);
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }

})();
```

#### `@mysql/xdevapi`

```js
const mysql = require('@mysql/xdevapi');

const MAX_CON = Number.parseInt(process.argv[2]) || 60;
const NB_REQ = Number.parseInt(process.argv[3]) || 500;

(async() => {

    try{
        const client = await mysql.getClient(
            {
                host : '127.0.0.1',
                port : 33060,
                user : 'test',
                password : 'test',
                schema : 'test'
            },
            {
                pooling : {
                    maxSize : MAX_CON
                }
            }
        );

        const before = Date.now();
        const promises = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < NB_REQ; i++){
            promises.push(new Promise(async resolve => {
                const con = await client.getSession();
                const prep = await con.sql('SELECT 1 from user');
                await prep.execute();
                await con.close();
                resolve()
            }));
        }

        await Promise.allSettled(promises);

        const time = (Date.now() - before) / 1000;
        const opBySecond = NB_REQ / time;
        console.log('The end : ', { opBySecond, time, NB_REQ, MAX_CON });

        await client.close();

        process.exit(0);
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }

})();
```

There things are worse.

Boths scripts run `500` requests with a pool of `60` connections with respective commands :

- `node parallel-mysql2.js 60 500`
- `node parallel-xdevapi.js 60 500`

And the results :

| Driver | Op / sec | time (s) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mysql2 | 8 771.92 | 0.057 |
| xdevapi | 76.66 | 6.522 |

`@mysql/xdevapi` is 110 times slower than `mysql2` with parallel execution. But it doesn't stop there.

If you try `node parallel-xdevapi.js 120 500` you may get an error :

```
/test/node/node_modules/@mysql/xdevapi/lib/DevAPI/Connection.js:920
            return state.error || new Error(errors.MESSAGES.ER_DEVAPI_CONNECTION_CLOSED);
                                  ^

Error: This session was closed. Use "mysqlx.getSession()" or "mysqlx.getClient()" to create a new one.
    at Object.getError (/test/node/node_modules/@mysql/xdevapi/lib/DevAPI/Connection.js:920:35)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/test/node/node_modules/@mysql/xdevapi/lib/DevAPI/Connection.js:677:40)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:715:12)

Node.js v18.0.0
```

While `node parallel-mysql2.js 120 500` output :

| Driver | Op / sec | time (s) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mysql2 | 7 142.86 | 0.07 |

**For the error thrown, my guess is that `mysql/xdevapi` doesn't handle the `mysql-server` max clients connected at a time. On my machine it's the default 128 value, since I have several process using the DB, running the script with a pool of `maxSize=120` crash the proces.**

It's the reason wy I didn't get any error in dev, but some hasardous crash in prod : with two pools of `maxSize=25` by process and 4 nodejs process launched in parallel, it reached a max of 200 mysql client connections. Any load of connections crashed one or several pools, and thus the process would not be able to recover from it. All subsquent calls to `client.getSession()` would hang indefinitly from this point.

## App Testing

I refactored the whole app DB connection handling to be sure it is consistant, then I created a DB component that can handle connector plugin/plugout.

I created two plugin : one using a `@mysql/xedvapi` driver, and another one using `mysql2`. Both shown similar results than those above when I run some benchmarks with `autocannon`.

I also created a connection wrapper that helps me know if any connection remains unclosed. No connection where left open anywere and were always returned to the pool after each query.

## Conclusion

In conclusion, I would say that it seems that something is wrong with the `@mysql/xdevapi` package at this time, in version `8.0.29` with mysql `8.0.29`, on nodejs `v18.0.0`, ubuntu `20.04`.

Either for it not handling the edge case when the mysql server cannot accept more connection, or for its slow perfromance, especially when queries are not sequential (which is the majority of the use cases in a webserver like nodejs application).

I solved my problem by switching from `@mysql/xdevapi` to `mysql2` for now.

## -------------- EDIT2 ----------------

For those who are or may be intrested into this discussion, follow this link to the [mysql bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=107507&thanks=2&notify=195).

Comment: Hi Ariart, I'm glad you were able to resolve the issue. One question though. When you say "user session" are you talking about an application session or a MySQL server session?

Also, keep in mind that a pool connection becomes "idle" when you call `Session.close()`,  and not when it "somehow" becomes inactive. There is no way for the connector to automatically determine if a connection is inactive or not, unless either the server or the application reports that. (Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of the MySQL X DevAPI connector for Node.js).

Comment: @ruiquelhas Hi, Thanks for your reply ! Yes, I mean an application user session in an HTTP server context. It's intresting, I assumed that the maxIdlTime would be a timeout since the last interaction with the MySQL server. It this sort of "somehow" I had in mind that would auto-release the connection. Instead, with what you said I now understand that `maxIdleTime` is for closing a connection that have been released since this time. I missread the doc on this point.

Comment: No, maxIdleTime is an option which allows the pool to internally close all connections that have been idle for more than that specific time (by default, they are never closed). If you somehow reach the MySQL server's interactive timeout (e.g. the value of `mysqlx_wait_timeout`), then the connection is also closed (no reason to become idle). When a connection is closed it should open space in the pool for new ones. Mind that some bug fixes and improvements have been introduced in later versions, so make sure you are using the latest one (8.0.29).

Comment: One more question. I just figured out that if the mysql server restart while the pool is active in a process, getSession() will never return any connexion from that point. The process have to be restarted too. The bad thing is that it doesn't throw any error, it just hang. Is there any way to detect when the mysql server have been restarted ?

Comment: That is weird. Should not happen, at the least in 8.0.29. Under what conditions does it happen exactly? Is the pool full? Any specific way of "restarting" the server? If you are on 8.0.29, please report it using the MySQL bug tracker (https://bugs.mysql.com/) under the "Connector for Node.js" category.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll properly investigate my code first. to be sure nothing is wrong by my side. I'm load testing it currently, their is several things I have to fix. But if I start my app, then run `systemctl restart mysql` in command line, my app doesn't report any error and just throw QueueTimeout errors indefinitly each time it try to hit the DB, even when mysql is ready again. And I work with the last connector/mysql version 8.0.29. I'm not able to create a simple, minimal reproductible example for now, though.

Comment: After further investigations, I have a clue on what happend. There seems to be something wrong with `@mysql/xdevapi`. I edited my answer for further references on SO. I'll post a bug report on the tracker.